# Css. Submenu disappears when hover the bottom menu

Tags: html, css

I have two menus. One at the top and one at the bottom.
Submenu at the top disappears when I hover the bottom menu

Here's [a link to css gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c9cb5f2f9d5f98eb59d)

And you can see example at this [gif image](https://gfycat.com/NeedyGreedyBorer)

Where is i am wrong?

**EDIT**
I'm using SmatrMenus jquery plugin

```
  <body>

<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 hidden-xs">
        <a class="logo" title="Go to Homepage" href="/"> <img src="assets/img/logos/logo-amber-blue.png"> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
          <a class="logo visible-xs" title="Go to Homepage" href="/"> <img src="assets/img/logos/logo-amber-blue.png"> </a>
          <nav id="uppernav" class="pull-right">
            <ul id="upmenu" class="sm upmenu">
              <li> <a href="index.html">Help</a>
                <ul>
                  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Void</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Void</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Void</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Void</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Void</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Void</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Void</a> </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li> <a href="index.html">Contacts</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="index.html">login</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <nav id="topnav"> <input id="topmenu-state" type="checkbox" /> 
            <label class="topmenu-btn" for="topmenu-state">
                <span class="topmenu-btn-icon"></span> Toggle main menu visibility
            </label>
            <ul id="topmenu" class="sm topmenu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Dropright Menu</a>
                    <ul>

                      <li><a href="#">Rossiyska</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Serenada Dret</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Merkava Is The Best</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Rossiyska</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Serenada Dret</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Merkava Is The Best</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Rossiyska</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Serenada Dret</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Merkava Is The Best</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Rossiyska</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam v Menus</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yatsenuck Di</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yatsenuck Di</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yatsenuck Di</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yatsenuck Di</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yatsenuck Di</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yatsenuck Di</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Choto Tam</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yatsenuck Di</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is the Blog page</h1> </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.smartmenus/1.0.0/jquery.smartmenus.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/smartmenus/js/jquery.smartmenus.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/cusom.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp59n8ub/)
contains all my styles

**Real** [example](https://timtemplate.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Can you please add the html too?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you made a [codepen](http://codepen.io) or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem.

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question, and do not try to go around the requirement that I'm sure was shown to you when you tried to post the link only. Please also make the fiddle work, it does not help if it's not able to replicate the problem.

Comment: where is the problem ? https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/dp59n8ub/3/

Comment: I can not understand why: on my PC menu is not working, but in the Fiddle it works... Oo

Comment: Please, see uploaded site here: https://timtemplate.azurewebsites.net/ problem still exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sm-core-css.css` has this rule

```
.sm {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The `z-index` is causing the bottom menu to appear over the top of the top drop-down menu.

> Either remove the rule for `z-index` or manually override it to `auto` and your menus will work correctly.